# Sending two values to PHP via ajax POST to query SQL db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to send two values from a form to another PHP using ajax post method. One value is the value that's already entered in an input box, and the other is a value that is being typed into another input box. It acts like a search box. I tried executing the SQL query in my SQL workbench and it returns the value properly. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
function searchq6(){
    var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val();
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='suburb']").val();
    $.post("search-suburb.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, st:searchstate},function(sbb){
        $("#sbb").html(sbb);
    //searchq7();
    });

}
```

This is the input box where I search and get the value from:

```
<input type="text" name="region" list="state" value="<?php echo $region;  ?>" placeholder="Select State" id="output">
Suburb:
        <input type="text" name="suburb" list="sbb" value="<?php echo $suburb;  ?>" onkeyup="searchq6()" id="output">
        <datalist id="sbb" name="taskoption6" >
                <option> </option>
        </datalist>
```

This is the search-suburb.php file:

```
$output = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
$st = $_POST['st'];
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations`  WHERE state="'.$st.'"  AND `title` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' ")or die("Could not  search!");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
}else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $suburb = $row['title'];

?>
    <option value="<?php echo $suburb; ?>"><?php echo $suburb; ?>  </option>
<?php
} // while
} // else
} // main if
```

Comment: var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val();
     you dont have input named region

Comment: I do. Added that code to the question

Comment: What happens with this code currently? Does it execute at all? This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Nope, nothing happens when I type inside the suburb field. Yeah I'm aware of the SQL injections

Comment: Open the developer console any errors? Does ajax request send?

Comment: http://site/search-suburb.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: why is this happening?

Comment: @YohanBlake : It seems to be some problem with your hosting server and make sure that the file is located at the right directory at which you are pointing??

Comment: Nothing really wrong with the server. Other ajax requests with one value executes correctly

Comment: Wrong quote usage. `"SELECT DISTINCT title FROM \`wp_locations\`  WHERE state="'` check your error logs in the future. Your double quote there closes the encapsulation your single quote is then starting a second string but with no concatenation.

Comment: Changed it to `"SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations` WHERE state='".$st."'  AND `title` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' "` . Now this searches, but I believe there are way too many results. The select box keeps loading with results and crashes the page. I think the `DISTINCT` isn't working. And on my console, it showed only the internal server error. How do I check the SQL query errors? @chris85

Comment: Get the PHP working first. Use `$_GET` and just load the page manually. Turn on error reporting.

Comment: Okay, so I'll set some value for the first variable. But how do I mimic the value for the `LIKE`? @chris85

Comment: Not sure what you mean if you are using `GET` `/page.php?searchVal=whatever&st=whateverelseyouarepassing`

Comment: nothing shows up on the page. Sorry for being a PIA. I'm new

Comment: Check your error logs. It is probably another syntax error.

Comment: `if (!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
}` still nothing

Comment: Is it still throwing a 500?

Comment: @chris85, nope it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from small snippets gathered through the comments 
Changed the query to:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations` WHERE state='".$st."'  AND `title` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' LIMIT 10")or die("Could not search!");
```

And the ajax to:

```
function searchq6(){
    var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val();
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='suburb']").val();
    $.post("search-suburb.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, st:searchstate})
    .done(function(sbb) {
        $("#sbb").html(sbb);
    });
    //searchq7();
}
```

Thanks for all the comments guys

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="region"  list="state" value="<?=(isset($_POST['region'])?$_POST['region']:'');?>" placeholder="Select State" id="output">
        Suburb:
<input type="text" name="suburb" onkeyup="searchq6()" list="sbb" value="<?=(isset($_POST['suburb'])?$_POST['suburb']:'');?>" onkeyup="searchq6()" id="output">
<datalist id="sbb" name="taskoption6"></datalist>
```

Javascript:

```
    function searchq6(){
        var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val();
        var searchTxt = $("input[name='suburb']").val();
        $.post("search-suburb.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, st:searchstate},function(sbb){
            var decode = jQuery.parseJSON(sbb); // parse the json returned array
            var str = ""; // initialize a stringbuilder
            $.each(decode, function (x, y) {
                str+="<option value='" + y.title +"'>";
            });
            $("#sbb").html(str);
        }); // end of post

    }// end of searchq6 function
```

Php:

```
$output = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $st = $_POST['st'];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations`  WHERE state='{$st}'  AND `title` LIKE  '%{$searchq}%' ")or die("Could not  search!");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
    } else{
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            $data[] = $row;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
} // main if
```

Comment: why did you add the `onkeyup="searchq6()` to the region too?

Comment: Sorry You can take out the onkeyup="searchq6()" to the suburb

Comment: I got it working from what I gathered from the comments. Thanks for your effort tho